# Need to select all subscription types for all customer IDs if the customer ID includes a 7 day trial

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a basic select statement that shows the customers who have seven day free trials:

```
select customer_id from purchases where description = '7 Day Free Trial'
```

This same customer id may also have additional descriptions in purchases indicating that they bought a subscription for a month, 6 months, one year as well as other options.

If the customer_id has a description = '7 Day Free Trial' then I need to select all the rows for these customer IDs. I want to see these rows not count them.

I know how to find the rows where customer_id is in the purchases table more than once with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM purchases WHERE customer_id IN
(
SELECT customer_id
FROM purchases
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY customer_id ASC
```

which produces:

```
customer_id status   description
12321       credit   7 Day Free Trial
12321       paid     1 Month Paid Subscription
78651       credit   6 Month Paid Subscription
78651       refund   6 Month Paid Subscription
45234       paid     30 Day Free Trial
45234       credit   1 Year Paid Description
```

But I am struggling to figure out how to approach the problem where if a customer _id has description = '7 Day Free Trial' select all the rows for that customer id.

An example of the output I desire is:

```
customer_id     description
12321       7 Day Free Trial 
12321       1 Month Paid Subscription
78651       7 Day Free Trial 
78651       1 Year Paid Description 
45234       7 Day Free Trial            
45234       6 Month Paid Subscription
```

Any suggestions appreciated. I am simply not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as cnt,
             sum( (p2.description = '7 Day Free Trial')::int ) over (partition by customer_id) as num_free_trials
      from purchases p
     ) p
where cnt >= 2 and num_free_trials > 0;
```

However, if you just want the descriptions, it might be good enough to put them in a single row -- using aggregation:

```
select customer_id, array_agg(description) as descriptions
from purchases p
group by customer_id
having count(*) filter (where p2.description = '7 Day Free Trial') > 0;
```

This allows you to use `distinct` to get only the unique descriptions, if you like.

In Redshift (the tag was changed after I answered), you can use:

```
having sum( (p2.description = '7 Day Free Trial')::int ) > 0
```

Comment: Very good. Thank you. I got your first suggestion working. It shows all the rows for customer ids that have trial and also shows their additional rows. The output includes customer IDs that have trial but not other subscription types. I am trying to see if your second solution can restrict my results to only customer ids with trial and additional subscription types for the same customer id.

Comment: trying to resolve this: 
`An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select customer_id, array_agg(description) as descriptions
from firecracker.productionrr_purchases p
group by customer_id
having count(*) filter (wher...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "filter" 
Position: 139; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.`

Comment: @Kierk . . . Your question is tagged Postgres, and that doesn't look like a Postgres error.  You can replace with a `having sum( (p2.description = '7 Day Free Trial')::int ) > 0`.

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff]working on this. This is AWS Redshift which I thought was postgresql. I believe it based on it. I don't know all the distinctions. Should I tag redshift instead?

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff] I got this to work `select customer_id,
listagg(description,',')
within group (order by description) as description
from purchases
group by customer_id
order by customer_id;' `

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff]which produces a result such as `251533 6 months subscription,7 Day Free Trial`

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff] But I really need each subscription period on its own line (as shown in my question) but still unclear how to achieve that.

Comment: @Kierk . . . Use the `exists` version then.

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff] The exists version would need this included for the customer id `'HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)'` .  How might I include that in the "exist" version? I get all  rows returned but I need all rows only when a customer id with a trial description also other description as well. So I am trying to include `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff]The output I need is shown at the end of my main post

Comment: @Kierk . . . I missed that condition and changed the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213431/discussion-between-kierk-and-gordon-linoff).

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff] You changed the first answer?  I am trying to troubleshoot and get clear on your query as well. But hitting this error on your first (updated) suggestion :  `An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as cnt,
             sum( (p2.description = '7 Day Free Trial')::int ) over (par...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "as" 
Position: 173; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.07s`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I get the results I was looking for at end of my post this way:

```
SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    id, 
    description 
FROM 
    firecracker.productionrr_purchases
WHERE 
    customer_id IN  (
        SELECT 
            customer_id 
        FROM            (
            SELECT  
                customer_id, 
                count(*) AS trial_user_rec
            FROM    
                firecracker.productionrr_purchases
            WHERE   
                customer_id IN  (
                    SELECT
                        customer_id 
                    FROM 
                        firecracker.productionrr_purchases
                    WHERE 
                        lower(description) LIKE lower('7 Day Free Trial')
                                )
            GROUP BY customer_id
                        )
    WHERE trial_user_rec>1
                    )
ORDER BY customer_id DESC
```

which returns

```
customer_id     description
12321       7 Day Free Trial 
12321       1 Month Paid Subscription
78651       7 Day Free Trial 
78651       1 Year Paid Description 
45234       7 Day Free Trial            
45234       6 Month Paid Subscription
```